# Performance Testing of OMNET++ applications

Tags: omnet++, perf

How can I check the performance of my OMNET++ application. I am aware of [Valgrid](https://omnetpp.org/pmwiki/index.php?n=Main.UsingValgrind), but I am looking for a tool that reports the method execution time and possible bottleneck in my program.

Is it possible to use [PERF](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Linux_Tools_Project/PERF/User_Guide) for performance testing?

Answer (score 0):

OMNeT++ simulations are regular C++ programs. Both Valgrind and Perf will work as expected to investigate which parts of your simulation are taking up the most time.